# how to add type annotation for mock function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have two mocked functions named mockedUnload and mockedMiniApp in test.tsx file;

```
let mockedUnload;
let mockedMiniApp; 

beforeEach(() => { 
   mockedUnload = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()); 
   mockedMiniApp = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({unload: mockedUnload}));
};
```

Obviously, the type of mockedUnload and mockedMiniApp is any. It maybe not a good practise, but I don't know what the type annotation I should assign to mockedUnload and mockedMiniApp. BTW, I have to wrapp these two functions into beforeEach for some reasons.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type these two mock function by using [jest.MockedFunction](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedfunction), which is available in the `@types/jest` module from version `24.9.0`.

```
type Unload = () => Promise<void>;

let mockedUnload: jest.MockedFunction<Unload>;
let mockedMiniApp: jest.MockedFunction<() => Promise<{ unload: Unload }>>;

beforeEach(() => {
  mockedUnload = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
  mockedMiniApp = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ unload: mockedUnload }));
});
```

Type definition:

```
 /**
     * Wrap a function with mock definitions
     *
     * @example
     *
     *  import { myFunction } from "./library";
     *  jest.mock("./library");
     *
     *  const mockMyFunction = myFunction as jest.MockedFunction<typeof myFunction>;
     *  expect(mockMyFunction.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(42);
     */
    type MockedFunction<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = MockInstance<ReturnType<T>, ArgsType<T>> & T;
```

**Update**: jest version < 24.9.0

Try:

```
type Unload = () => Promise<void>;

let mockedUnload: jest.Mock<ReturnType<Unload>>;
let mockedMiniApp: jest.Mock<Promise<{ unload: Unload }>>;

mockedUnload = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
mockedMiniApp = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ unload: mockedUnload }));

// or
let mockedUnload1: jest.MockInstance<ReturnType<Unload>>;
let mockedMiniApp1: jest.MockInstance<Promise<{ unload: Unload }>>;

mockedUnload = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
mockedMiniApp = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ unload: mockedUnload }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I got error showing "jest has no exported member named MockedFunction. Did you mean isMockFunction?" Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: @jobseeker What's the version of jest are you using? Did you install the type definition `@types/jest` package?

Comment: I installed @types/jest: "23.3.12" and jest version is "^25.5.4"

Comment: @jobseeker Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about if we are not allowed to upgrade @types/jest, any other jest.***  functions can be used for this case?

Comment: @jobseeker Updated answer. Try it

Comment: great!!! thank you so much